# Non-static method requires a target at the time of joining two tables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to join my SUser table and TVSeries table and store the data into a mapper table but during joining these two tables this error occurs

I have tried with LINQ query syntax and also lambda expression but same error occurs for both of them

Here is the UserController class

```
public class UserController : Controller
    {
        // GET: User
        IRepository<TVSeries> repository1 = new TVSeriesRepository(new TVSFlixDbContext());
        IRepository<SUser> repository3 = new SUserRepository(new TVSFlixDbContext());
        TVSFlixDbContext db = new TVSFlixDbContext();
        public ActionResult User_Home()
        {

            return View(TempData["Matched_Data"] as SUser);
        }
        public PartialViewResult TVSList()
        {
            IList<TVSeries> TVSL = repository1.GetAll();
            return PartialView("TVSList", TVSL);
        }

        public ActionResult ADD(int ID)
        {
            SUser su = TempData["Matched_Data"] as SUser;
            var join_data = db.UTMappers.Include("User").Include("tvs").Where(p => p.UserID == su.UserID).Where(q => q.tvsID == ID).ToList();
            TempData["Joined_Data"] = join_data;
            User_TVSeries_Mapper mapper = TempData["Joined_Data"] as User_TVSeries_Mapper;
            db.UTMappers.Add(mapper);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }



    }
}
```

it is my SUser model

```
public class SUser
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        [Custom_Rules_Name]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Age { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string DOB { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Type is Required")]
        public string User_Type { get; set; }
        public List<User_TVSeries_Mapper> utm { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my TVSeries model

```
public class TVSeries
    {
        [Key]
        public int TVSID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Release_Date { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }


        public IList<User_TVSeries_Mapper> utm { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my mapper

```
public class User_TVSeries_Mapper
    {
        public SUser User { get; set; }
        public TVSeries tvs { get; set; }
        [Key,Column(Order =1)]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [Key,Column(Order =3)]
        public int tvsID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="TV Series")]
        public string tvsName { get; set; }

    }
```

And This is the partial view of TVSList

```
@model IEnumerable<TVSFlix.Models.TVSeries>

<table class="table" border="1" style="width:500px">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th>
            Options
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("ADD", "ADD","User", new { id=item.TVSID },null)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

this is the error

> Non-static method requires a target

```
Line 30:        {
Line 31:            SUser su = TempData["Matched_Data"] as SUser;
Line 32:            var join_data = db.UTMappers.Include("User").Include("tvs").Where(p => p.UserID == su.UserID).Where(q => q.tvsID == ID).ToList();
Line 33:            TempData["Joined_Data"] = join_data;
Line 34:            User_TVSeries_Mapper mapper = TempData["Joined_Data"] as User_TVSeries_Mapper;
```

on line 32

I want to join SUser and TVSeries Table and store the data into mapper class after add link is clicked

Comment: After clinking the add ink i get this error

Answer (score 0):

db.UTMappers.Include("User").Include("tvs").Where(p => p.UserID == su.UserID).Where(q => q.tvsID == ID).ToList();

I don't see a join or a custom select operation in here. If you want to join the tables use ".Join()". "Include" will just include related entities and "where" will filter them out.